# Get open cases counts for particular user in specific date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a SSRS report and I want to get the open cases for particular user in specific date range like below.

1. I have table called User from there I'm getting user info(User1,User2,User3).
2. I have open cases in the table management under description table.
3. I have c_date column in class table.

And I have 3 parameters user, startdate and enddate

And I need to use c_date between startdate and enddate.

If User enters startdate as 2019-01-01 and enddate as 2019-31-01, then I want to display the User1 who has open count.

For 0-5days and User1 who has open count for 6-11 days and same thing for user2 also.

Expected output:

```
User    0-5days  6-11days  
----   -------    -------   
User1    2         1                 
User2    1         4                  
User3    5         0
```

Explanation: User 1 has 2 open cases between 0-5 days means when I enter date range consider 2019-01-01 and 2019-31-01 so I have 2 open cases between first 0-5 days(2019-01-01 and 2019-05-01) and 1 open cases between next 6-11 days(2019-06-01 and 2019-11-01) etc.

Can I get result like this?

Comment: The basic req you mentioned can be achieved but in your current example will your columns be dynamic I.e they will be 0-5 then 6-11 and then 12-18 and then 19-24 and so on or they will be always 2 columns as 0-5 and 6-11? In short what is the criteria for your columns?

Comment: yeah actually i have columns upto 28days but i only asked for 2 columns

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would help.

Comment: Hi already i mentioned the tables and data which are used. hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do this in the dataset query if possible. Use CASE and DATEDIFF to group your data something like

```
SELECT
    [User],
    [AnyOtherColumns],
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startdate, c_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(d, @startdate, c_date) BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN '6-11'
        ELSE 'older'
    END AS [Age]
    FROM myTable
    WHERE [User] = @user
        AND c_date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

> (done from memory so may not be perfect)

In your report you can use [User] on your row group,  [Age] as your column group and then simply count any of the columns to give you the actual count of records.

You could do the counting in SQL too but I'm not sure if you need the detail for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have two columns,
My approach would be 
Have 3 parameters, one for user and other for To and from date.

Now selecting these parameters, add them to your dataset query as filter
Note you can apply filter on ssrs dataset as well but I would prefer on query level so that you have data been filtered and loaded only req one.

Then you can apply summing and grouping based on user and play around with Ssrs tablix to get the desired results.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3453/sql-server-reporting-services-reports-with-optional-query-parameters/

https://reportsyouneed.com/ssrs-tip-put-parameters-in-your-query-not-your-filter/

Comment: Yeah we have 3 parameters and can you please provide query condition how can i get for each date range for open cases?

Comment: I have updated answer with few external links which will give you idea how to play with parameters and query.

Comment: Hi i know how to use parameters and ssrs report but before that i need to be with stored proc which has this conditions. i need the query to get the desired output. can you please help